# How do I create tabs in an admin page?

Tags: 8

How do I create a tab in the admin page using a custom module?

The files defining the routes, links and task are the following.

### cst_core.routing.yml

```
cst.admin:
  path: '/admin/MyCustomModule'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\cst_core\Controller\CstController::content'
    link_id: 'cst.admin'
    _title: 'MyCustomModule Management'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'cst admin'
    
cst.admin_menu:
  path: '/admin/MyCustomModule/menu-mgmt'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\cst_core\Controller\CstController::content'
    link_id: 'cst.admin_menu'
    _title: 'MyCustomModule Menu Management'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'cst menu'

cst.admin_menu_menu:
  path: '/admin/MyCustomModule/menu-mgmt/menu'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\cst_core\Controller\CstController::content'
    link_id: 'cst.admin_menu_menu'
    _title: 'MyCustomModule Menu Management'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'cst menu'

cst.admin_menu_menu_taba:
  path: '/admin/MyCustomModule/menu-mgmt/menu/taba'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\arm_core\Controller\CstController::content'
    link_id: 'cst.admin_menu_menu_taba'
    _title: 'MyCustomModule Menu Management tabs'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'cst menu'
```

### cst_core.links.menu.yml

```
cst.admin:
title: 'MyCustomModule'
description: 'MyCustomModule System'
parent: system.admin
route_name: cst.admin
weight: -20

cst.admin_menu:
title: 'Menu'
description: 'Menu Management.'
parent: cst.admin
route_name: cst.admin_menu
weight: 0

cst.admin_menu_menu:
title: 'Menu'
description: 'Menus.'
parent: cst.admin_menu
route_name: cst.admin_menu_menu
weight: 0
```

### cst_core.links.task.yml

```
cst.admin_menu_menu_taba:
route_name: cst.admin_menu_menu_taba
title: 'tab-menu A'
base_route: cst.admin_menu_menu
```

With this, I should have:

-- MyCustomModule

--- Menu Management

---- Menu

+++++ **tab-menu A (as a tab)** --> but this didn't happend T_T

something like this:

[image: something like this:]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tab is actually appear in this path: /admin/MyCustomModule/menu-mgmt/menu/taba

but it didn't appear in: /admin/MyCustomModule/menu-mgmt/menu

the reason is:

you need to add menu_menu in task as well, as follow:

```
cst.admin_menu_menu:
  title: 'Menu'
  route_name: cst.admin_menu_menu
  base_route: cst.admin_menu_menu
```

so your **cst_core.links.task.yml** should look like:

```
cst.admin_menu_menu:
  title: 'Menu'
  route_name: cst.admin_menu_menu
  base_route: cst.admin_menu_menu

cst.admin_menu_menu_taba:
  title: 'sub-menu A'
  route_name: cst.admin_menu_menu_taba
  base_route: cst.admin_menu_menu
```

Answer (score 2):

if I suppose `cst.admin_menu_menu_tabA:` is your sub-menu A then also add

> `cst_core.links.task.yml` for tabs or sub menu tabs in an admin page

then add the following code below

```
cst.admin_menu_menu_tabA:
  route_name: cst.admin_menu_menu_tabA
  title: 'sub-menu A'
  base_route: cst.admin_menu_menu
```

proceed so on for the rest of the tabs..

and also add a route for `cst.admin_menu_menu_tabA` in cst_core.routing.yml

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, but it didn't happened, maybe do you mind to help elaborate whats the different route_name and base_route?
my structure actually like this: admin page- module main page - menu page- menu_menu (sub menu) - (and i like to build tab inside menu_menu page)

Comment: @AnD route_name is used to affix the current tab whereas  base_route is used to describe under which parent tab it should appear .

Comment: so in my case, base_route should be: cst.admin_menu_menu and route_name should be: cst.admin_menu_menu_tabA (new route), correct? let me try this

Comment: hold on... but how about task name, you name it: cst.admin_menu_menu - is it should linked to something?

Comment: c the route name should be same as the main attribute letz say in ur case if route_name: cst.admin_menu_menu_tabA and base_route:cst.admin_menu_menu 
then it should be under cst.admin_menu_menu_tabA: 
and also add aroute for cst.admin_menu_menu_tabA

Comment: @AnD i hv edited d answer can u  try that 1nce and comment back..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39726/discussion-between-and-and-make-me-alive).

Comment: Good example can be seen at `core/modules/locale/locale.links.task.yml`